# Transforming pdf to html in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, pdf, pdf2htmlex

## Python 2.6

I'm trying to parse my pdf files and one way to do that is to transform it into html and extracting headings along with their paragraphs.
So, I tried pdf2htmlEX and it converted my pdf into html without disturbing my pdf format... So far, I was happy but when I tried to access my headings by using such commands:

```
>> import subprocess

>> path = "/home/administrator/Documents/pdf_file.pdf"
>> subprocess.call(["pdf2htmlEX" , path])
```

But when I opened my html file it was giving me unnecessary stuff along with my text and more importantly my text doesn't have heading tags just bunch of divs and span.

```
 >> f = open('/home/administrator/Documents/pdf_file.html','r')
 >> f = f.read()
 >> print f
```

I even tried to access it using BeautifulSoup

```
>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

>> soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
>> soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'site-content'}).h1
```

It didn't gave me anything coz there was no tags. I have also tried HTMLParser

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

```
# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class myhtmlparser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
         self.reset()
         self.NEWTAGS = []
         self.NEWATTRS = []
         self.HTMLDATA = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
         self.NEWTAGS.append(tag)
         self.NEWATTRS.append(attrs)
    def handle_data(self, data):
         self.HTMLDATA.append(data)
    def clean(self):
         self.NEWTAGS = []
         self.NEWATTRS = []
         self.HTMLDATA = []

parser = myhtmlparser()
parser.feed(f)

# Extract data from parser
tags  = parser.NEWTAGS
attrs = parser.NEWATTRS
data  = parser.HTMLDATA

# Clean the parser
parser.clean()

# Print out our data
#print tags
print data
```

but they all are not fulfilling my required desire. All I want is to extract each headings along with their required paragraphs from that html file is that too much to ask... :p  I searched almost every site and read almost everything on this but all my effort ends in vain. Plz guide me in this...

Comment: "extract each headings" In the strict sense there is no such thing as "headings" in a PDF. Unless it is a Tagged PDF. In which case you would want to look for a PDF to HTML derivation tool which would preserve the PDF Tagging. "their required paragraphs" Again, same as headings, unless your PDF is tagged, there is no such thing as a paragraph in a PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

If it's python3 and up, it should be

```
outputFilename = outputDir + filename.replace(".pdf",".html")
subprocess.run(["pdf2htmlEX",file,outputFilename])
```